# Kernel / Boot auditing in RHEL 7?

Tags: rhel, linux-audit

In RHEL5 and RHEL6, I could add `audit=1` to start kernel-level auditing during boot before the boot process got as far as starting `auditd`. Now, in RHEL7, I can't find any mention of `audit=1` as a kernel argument.

Has anyone seen a definitive document on kernel/system auditing at boot time? Is just having the `audit` RPM installed and `systemctl enable auditd` sufficient on reboot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The RHEL 7.x [documentation on auditing](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/security_guide/chap-system_auditing) doesn't mention the kernel parameter at all (somehow I thought the RHEL 6.x documentation did mention it but I can't seem to find it now).

The manual page for `auditd` (package `audit-2.7.6-3.el7.x86_64`) on a RHEL 7.4 system, however, has the following:

> A boot param of `audit=1` should be added to ensure that all processes that run before the audit daemon starts is marked as auditable by the kernel. Not doing that will make a few processes impossible to properly audit.

So, although it's not mentioned in the distribution documentation, you *do* still need the `audit=1` kernel parameter.